# java.io.FileNotFoundException Save/Load in internal storage android

Tags: java, android, save, load, internal-storage

I'm trying to save data from the app to internal storage and load it back, but I feel like I miss something and the file is not found in the load.

Save code:

```
private void saveScanData(List<MyStack> surf) throws IOException {
    Log.i(TAG, "Saving");
    String filename = String.format("Scan%05d.data", scanNumber);
    scanNumber += 1;
    ObjectOutput out;

    File outFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), filename);
    out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outFile));

    out.writeObject(surf);
    out.close();
}
```

Load code:

```
public void load(View view) {
    ObjectInput in;
    List<MyStack> surf= null;
    try {
        in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("Scan%05d.data"));
        surf= (List<MyStack>) in.readObject();
        in.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    Model model= new Model(surf);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, EditorPresenter.class);
    intent.putExtra("model", model);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: In order to avoid any other factors, have you tried calling saveScanData immediately followed by load to see what happens?  If that works, then it is likely a question of when (or if) it is being called.

Comment: Save and load are in two different activites, but still I tried doing it in the same session of the app(saving, going back to main activity and trying the load) and I got this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the open openFileOutput and openfileInput method instead of opening new Input and output stream.

http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

Moreover, you are trying to save the file in the ExternalStorage folder.
`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`. Writting in that folder requires Android permissions on the AndroidManifest

Comment: openFileOutput and openfileInput don't provide the writeObject method to save objects.

The android manifest should be fine with `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />`right?

Comment: out= new ObjectOutputStream(openFileOutput(fileName,Context.MODE_PRIVATE ));

Comment: Wrong 1st argument type. Found: 'java.io.File', required: 'java.lang.String'.

Can't call opeFileOutput with File, but only with the string name, but in this way I lose the directory environment

Comment: As 1st parameter you just need to use the fileName (not the File object).
With internal storage, the application has a pre-designated folder where files are writen in. openFileOutput and openFileInput open a file for read/write in that folder.

Comment: This worked out, I changed both save and load in that way and seems the app can find the location. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

You write into the file with the name

```
String.format("Scan%05d.data", scanNumber)
```

But you read the file with the name

```
"Scan%05d.data"
```

Either change your object input stream creation or use another approach to create the filename.

```
new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(String.format("Scan%05d.data", scanNumber));
```

Comment: Nice, I totally didn't catch that, but you're right.  If that isn't directly his problem, it is at least a problem that needs to be fixed for sure.

Comment: Yeah, that was definetely an error to fix, but still I get the same FileNotFoundException

Answer (score 0):

You are writing to external storage:

```
new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), filename);
```

You are reading from nowhere:

```
new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("Scan%05d.data"));
```

If you want to use external storage, use external storage **in both places**, not just one.